# MVC creating a view issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
   public ActionResult AlbumList3(
   {
   AlbumService albumservice = new AlbumService();
   var PagingViewModel = new PagingViewModel<Album> { Query = albumservice.GetAlbums(),  ViewData = ViewData };
   return View(PagingViewModel);
   }
```

I am trying to create view for the above coding. And MY pagingviewmodel class is generic class `PagingViewModel<T>`, which I cannot select `Viewdataclass` drop down while making view.

So when i create a strongly typed => empty view then i cannot get values of the entity.

Gives below error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'MvcApplication1.Models.PagingViewModel' to
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first line of your view add:

```
@model PagingViewModel<Album>
```

you can then do:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Query)
```

to loop through the albums.

**Update**

In the case of ASPX views, change:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"
```

To

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PageViewModel<Album>>"
```

And to access the items:

```
<% foreach(var item in Model.Query) { %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..
But i am not using "Razor View Page"..
I m using .aspx view page no razor.